# Can't change location of .authinfo

Tags: email, smtpmail

While using emacs e-mails, receiving works fine. Sending does not. If I place my `.authfile` in the home folder sending mails works fine. It does not ask for `smtp server` or user or password.

If I move the file to a different folder and use 
`(setq auth-sources "/different_folder/.authinfo")`
it asks me to provide the `smpt server` and all credentials. 
It looks like the variable doesn't work.

Anyone some suggestions on this?

Thanks

Comment: The doc-string says that this should be a list, which can contain multiple elements.  How about trying:  `(setq auth-sources '("/different_folder/.authinfo"))`

Comment: This improves the behaviour as emacs seems to know the `smtp server` but still asks me for my user name and password

Comment: Sounds like a bug that you should report. Use `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Telling us your version of emacs and showing us the (redacted) contents of your .authinfo would help. Note that 'auth-source' does a fair amount of caching, so it's a good idea to restart Emacs after changing variables that affect it.

Comment: Restarting doesn't help. Emacs Version is 25.2 and the redacted content of `.authinfo` is as follows: `machine smtp.gmail.com login myusername port 587 password mypassword`. I don't think that the content is problem because it worked at the standard location.

Comment: I updated my emacs verison to 26.1 from `brew cask` as I'm running on `macos`

Comment: I am running emacs 25.2.2 and it does read authinfo from a different location (after restarting). So it doesn't look like a bug.
Have you checked the permissions of "/different_folder/.authinfo"?